# Many-to-many recursive table definition in SQLAlchemy results in AmbiguousForeignKeysError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I'm trying to create a table of *profiles* where profiles, tests, and folders can be children of profiles, but I'm getting an *AmbiguousForeignKeysError* when I call `create_all(db)`. My idea for a single table, which then references itself via a mapper or association table seems like it should work, but I haven't been able to get sqlalchemy to cooperate. I used examples for a many-to-many relationship on the sqlalchemy website to create my code. Here's my snippet:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Enum, Table, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship,validates
from core.coyote.models import Base #declarative base

association_table = Table('association', Base.metadata,
    Column('left_id', Integer, ForeignKey('profile_member.id')),
    Column('right_id', Integer, ForeignKey('profile_member.id'))
)

class ProfileMember(Base):
    __tablename__ = "profile_member"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250),nullable=True)
    type = Column(Enum("Test","Profile","Folder"))
    children = relationship("ProfileMember",secondary=association_table)
```

I also plan to put in some validation code so that I can enforce some parentage rules. Here is the complete error I'm getting:

> sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship ProfileMember.children - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables via secondary table 'association'.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference from the secondary table to each of the parent and child tables

Any clues as to things I can try would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify how to join to the secondary table:

```
children = relationship("ProfileMember", secondary=association_table,
                        primaryjoin=id == association_table.c.left_id,
                        secondaryjoin=association_table.c.right_id == id)
```

Comment: this works somewhat, but now python is complaining that "name 'association_table' is not defined". I'm not sure what the scope of those statements are

Comment: @TonyH It's exactly the same as the `secondary` keyword param. You should get that error regardless of whether or not you have `primaryjoin` and `secondaryjoin`.

Comment: Thanks again. Actually it was that I had enclosed the statement in quotes.